# JQuery not selecting SELECT

Tags: jquery, select, blur

I'm pulling values from options of a 'select' element using JQuery blur() method, but for some reason it always pulls the value of selectedIndex = 0 and not the selectedIndex that I chose.

Here's the --> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7LcX/) <--  For some reason the first row works fine (Length) but none of the other rows work.'

Type a number in any textbox (EXCEPT FOR THE FIRST ONE 'LENGTH') and then choose an item from the adjacent SELECT box, then click away from the SELECT

You will see that the code is always selecting the value of option=0 in every SELECT element. And it also can't recognize my 'data-hid' property as a number (see html in textbox element)

Can someone help? I've been stuck on this for a day now.

**Also, for some reason this only works in JQuery 1.7.2 and NOT on the 1.9 releases (it doesn't like the 'option:selected' code, does anyone know how that snippet could comply with the latest releases?

```
$('select').blur(function() {

//Get the value of the option chosen
var unit = $(this + 'option:selected').val();

//If the selectedIndex is 0 then focus on the select and make the user chose a unit.
  if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') == 0) {
      $(this).focus();
    return;
} else {


//Remove the 'd' in front of the 'select' element ID and you will have the ID of the   textbox
        var txt = "#" + $(this).attr("id").substr(1);

//Get the numerical value of the textbox
        var mval = parseFloat($(txt).val());

            if ($(txt).attr('data-hid') == "OFF") {
                var hid = mval / unit;
                $(txt).attr('data-hid', hid);
                 alert("hid = " + hid + "\nmval = " + mval + "\nunit = " + unit);
            }
            else 
            {
                var hid = $(txt).attr('data-hid');
                var newtxt = hid * unit;
                $(txt).val(newtxt);
            }
}
main();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use `$(this).val()` which gives you the selected value of the select item? There is no need to specifically get the option element first.

http://api.jquery.com/val/

The documentation even says so.

Comment: Lol...everything works! I guess I tried to complicate it too much. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
//Get the value of the option chosen
var unit = $(this + 'option:selected').val();
```

should be:

```
var unit = $(':selected', this).val();
```

To understand why (besides looking at the jQuery documentation), try this line just under your `blur` function:

```
console.log(this + 'option:selected'); //outputs something like [object HTMLSelectElement]option:selected
```

You *could* do something like:

```
console.log('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' option:selected'); //outputs something like #mySelectBox option:selected
```

but now we're just getting a bit ridiculous :D ...but maybe it helps you understand how the jQuery selector works at least =0]

[Torsten's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15160608/622129) answer is really the right way to do this

Comment: Actually it should be `var unit = $(':selected', this).val();` since `var unit = $(':selected', unit).val();` wouldn't work.

Comment: @j08691: sorry about that, mistyped. Not enough coffee yet this morning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of a select, that is, the value of the option that was selected, the correct way to do it is:

```
$(this).val(); // Inside the .blur "this" points to your select
```

Then instead of checking if the selected index is 0, you can check if value is empty, if it is empty return, otherwise the person has selected a valid value from your select.

Also, on your fiddle html the first option is "selected", you dont have to put that keyword to make the first option behave as default, if none is selected then the first one is selected.

Additionally, are you sure you want this event to trigger on blur? wouldnt .change fit your purpose better. From your description the "workflow" is to type a number in the input then select a unit on the select. Change triggers as soon as user has selected a value, blur triggers only when select field loses focus.

Comment: I've thought about .change, but once the user types a number and selects a unit - then that number is locked in. If they want to see what their value converts to (in another unit) they can just select another unit. If i do .change - and the user accidentally selects a unit - then they will have to reset the entire form and start over. Blur method is not ideal, but I think it works best in this situation.

Comment: I see, as soon as a unit is chosen its gets "submited". Only way i can think that could be better than .blur for this situation is separating the "submit" from the select with a button

Comment: True. Although I will take your advice on the .change. When the user wants to see what their number converts to - I'll use the .change but when they first input their number I'll keep the .blur